# Can't Use "Script MT Bold" font in canvas

Tags: canvas, fonts

The Font is installed in my computer. I have also downloaded the font and provided its url with css

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'scripts';
        src: url('SCRIPTBL.eot');
        src: local('SCRIPTBL'), url('SCRIPTBL.woff') format('woff'), url('SCRIPTBL.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
    h1 {
        font-family: 'scripts';
    }
</style>
```

For h1 tag its working properly but when i am trying to use this font in canvas. Then its not working.

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#293980";
ctx.font = "bolder italic 75px scripts";
ctx.fillText(stuName, canvas.width / 2 - ctx.measureText(stuName).width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
```

The font location and url is perfectly fine. Console shows no error regarding that. I have tried using "Arial","Verdana","Helvetica" etc etc. They are working but "scripts"->"Script MT Bold" is not working.
Here is a codepen for this. https://codepen.io/Dry_Ruffian/pen/KKPBmar
But I am not able to insert font in this pen.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. The codepen you provided has too much unrelated code that is not runnable by us. You could [make a runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) from your question directly by using [any webfont](https://fonts.google.com/). Also, here you wrote `ctx.font = "bolder italic 75px scripts";` while in the codepen it's written `ctx.font = "bolder italic 75px Script MT Bold";` the  one in the question should be correct.